# Error using Dr. Memory with Visual Studio project: libraries needed by the application are missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, allegro5, dr-memory

I have a Visual Studio 2017 project which uses the Allegro 5 library. I installed Dr. Memory using the latest .msi installer and followed [these](http://www.drmemory.org/docs/page_prep.html) instructions to set up my project to work with Dr. Memory. However, when I try to run Dr. Memory, I see a popup which says "The program can't start because allegro-5.0.10-monolith-md-debug.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." In the output window, I see:

```
WARNING: libraries needed by the application are missing.  Check that it runs successfully 
on its own and check that all needed libraries are in its directory or on the PATH.
WARNING: application exited with abnormal code 0xc0000135
```

However, the project runs successfully on its own, and the PATH variable does contain the debug dll. How can I get Dr. Memory to get the dll when running it?

Answer (score -1):

You need to take every header from your project directory (for instance if you're running Visual Studio, this is where your ProjectName.vcxproj and ProjectName.vcxproj.filters files are) and put it in the same folder as your project's .exe file found in (ProjectName)/Debug.